# Self association in rails to keep track of related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-admin

I have a model named **Letter** and an other one named **LetterTracking** :

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :letter_trackings, as: :trackable
end
```

and:

```
class LetterTracking < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :letter
    has_many :letter_trackings, as: :trackable 
end
```

this is my create table migration for Letter Tracking:

```
class CreateLetterTrackings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :letter_trackings do |t|
      t.integer  :trackable_id, default: 0, null: false, unique: true
      t.string   :trackable_type
      t.text     :paraph
      t.string   :status
      t.string   :assignee
      t.belongs_to :letter
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

as you can see in below screen shots when I select a tracking record for the second tracking the relation is ok but when ever I add the third letter tracking the second one relation removes and the last one keeps the association.
**What I want is to keep the letter tracking in each record not by the last one.** I mean some thing like nested records in which I can keep the related records.
any Idea ?
Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do your related controllers and views look like?

Comment: @ spickermann I'm not started to generate Controllers and views yet I just want to manage it through Rails_admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as a second thought the polymorphic relation seems quite useless for keeping track in this case. The thing which fits best here is tree based relation I suppose.
this is my *LetterTracking.rb*

```
class LetterTracking < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :letter
    has_many :children, class_name: "LetterTracking", foreign_key: "parent_id"                             
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "LetterTracking"
end
```

and this is my *letter.rb*

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :letter_trackings
end
```

and finaly the *LetterTrackings Migration*:

```
class CreateLetterTrackings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :letter_trackings do |t|
      t.references :parent, index: true
      t.text     :paraph
      t.string   :status
      t.string   :assignee
      t.belongs_to :letter, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can have the records of the lettertrackings join together like a tree while keeping the letter id in every single record! Yep :)